# "Failed to validate config metadata of ordering config: duplicate consenter" while joining orderer to a channel in Hyperledger Fabric v2.4

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm getting **"cannot join: failed to determine cluster membership from join-block: failed to validate config metadata of ordering config: duplicate consenter** error when attempting to join a new orderer node to a new channel.

```
Status: 400
{
    "error": "cannot join: failed to determine cluster membership from join-block: failed to validate config metadata of ordering config: duplicate consenter: server cert: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----<serverCertificate>-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n, client cert: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----<clientCertificate>-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
```

The `<serverCertificate>` and `<clientCertificate>` embedded in the error message are both tls certificates. The `<clientCertificate>` is for one of the nodes which I'm not even attemptiing to joining to a channel yet.

I'm following the "Creating a Channel" tutorial from version 2.4 documentation, without docker.

- I have created all the required certificates (both tls and id
  certificates) and folder structures.
- The orderer nodes are successfully started.
- The genesis block is successfully created.

However, the above error occurs when I run the following CLI, irrespective of the referenced orderers' endpoint.

```
osnadmin channel join --channelID channel.ppty --config-block /home/dionly/hyperledger/fabric/2.4.3/config/genesis_block.pb -o hlfdev:7443 --ca-file $OSN_TLS_CA_ROOT_CERT --client-cert $ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT --client-key $ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY
```

I have checked the orderer.yaml and configtx.yaml files for duplicate reference to the offending certificates. None was found.

I have also queried TLS CA

```
$ ./fabric-ca-client identity list -u https://hlfdev:7054 --tls.certfiles tls-root-cert/tls-ca-cert.pem --mspdir tls-ca/tlscaadmin/msp
```

in case somehow I managed to create a duplicate registry. That does not seem to be the case.

I have gone through the tutorial more times than I can count and always get stock at this same point.

I'd really appreciate any suggestion on what is causing this and how to progress past it.

Comment: did you find solution for this problem?